# Change UIImageview shape to match shape

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, xcode5

I have had a really good look around the forums and cannot find an answer to my question that makes sense to me..so I am hoping somebody can shed light on this.

I have a cloud and another object and when these make contact the game is over (really basic explanation of the game) - the problem I have is the cloud, being in the shape of..well..a cloud, and the image view being a rectangle means that my other object makes contact and runs the method game over before, visually, it has made any contact.

Please help me! :-)

Comment: so you want to *distort* the image view (or the image inside it) to exactly fit the cloud, or whatever you have in that shape?

Comment: I suggest using sprite kit or coco2d.

Comment: Hi Michael.- yes exactly, the image view is by default a rectangle but I need it to conform to the shape of the cloud.

Comment: I did see something about coco2d - would I implement all the code within coco2d?

Comment: I am still struggling with this, cannot find a clear tutorial anywhere.